# Spring Boot 2 OAuth2 starter changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to migrate one of my projects from  Spring Boot **1.5.10.RELASE** to **2.0.0.RC1**. And seems like they made some major changes in  API, because I cannot find **@EnableOAuth2Sso** and **UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer** that I used to make some configuration for Azure AD and OAuth2.

Where can I find new documentation or change list for Spring Boot 2.0.0 and OAuth2?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading [Spring Boot 2.0 official migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide).

To quote from there, the most interesting thing for you will be:

> Functionality from the Spring Security OAuth project is being migrated
>   to core Spring Security. Dependency management is no longer provided
>   for that dependency and Spring Boot 2 provides OAuth 2.0 client
>   support via Spring Security 5.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on bjedrzejewski's answer with the specific artifact information and how I found it:

After discussions in [an existing GitHub issue on spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11032#issuecomment-372100443), I was eventually led to the annotation's location in the 2.0.0 release. It has been moved to a project completely new to the 2.0.0 release artifacts.

To resolve this issue and migrate your project, add the artifact [org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure) to your dependency management configuration.

Comment: Before it's suggested, I could not clarify this or otherwise provide this answer in the original GitHub discussion location, as a project maintainer chose to lock the conversation immediately after answering the question