# Spring Boot 2.0.0 + OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Does Spring Boot 2 + Sping Security OAuth2 still support the `@AuthorizationServer` annotation? From reading the release notes some things haven't been ported over:

[Oauth2 Support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M5-Release-Notes#oauth-20-support)

Here is the relevant section of my `build.grade`:

**Auth Server**

```
// security
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}"
// oauth
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2
compile "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.1.RELEASE"
```

**Client Server**

```
// support for Oauth2 user token services not yet migrated into Spring Boot 2.0
compile "org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
```

And right now my Authorization Server Oauth2 endpoints just return a 401 when i try to pass a client-id and client-secret in as `Basic Authentication` to `/oauth/token`. Passing in a username and password gives a different code path. So it looks like the OAuth filters aren't quite lined up.

I also found this as well: [Spring Boot 2 OAuth2 starter changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641560/spring-boot-2-oauth2-starter-changes).

Has there been a configuration update or do I need a different set of gradle dependencies to restore the Authorization Server to it's previous state?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I wanted to close the loop on this question. In addition to encrypting the client-secrets. The RedisTokenStore issue has also been resolved as of Spring OAuth 2.3.2: [Spring OAuth 2.3.2](https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/12/spring-security-oauth-2-3-2-released)

Comment: so it oauth2 support just not available yet with spring security? I'm confused about Spring Security 5 + Spring Boot 2. I'll look more into org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Security 5 uses a modernized password storage, see [OAuth2 Autoconfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server.html):

> If you use your own authorization server configuration to configure the list of valid clients through an instance of `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` as shown below, take note that the passwords you configure here are subject to the modernized password storage that came with Spring Security 5.

To solve your problem, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#troubleshooting):

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> The following error occurs when one of the passwords that are stored has no id as described in the section called “Password Storage Format”.
>
> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
>      at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:233)
>      at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:196)
> ```
>
> The easiest way to resolve the error is to switch to explicitly provide the `PasswordEncoder` that you passwords are encoded with. The easiest way to resolve it is to figure out how your passwords are currently being stored and explicitly provide the correct `PasswordEncoder`. If you are migrating from Spring Security 4.2.x you can revert to the previous behavior by exposing a `NoOpPasswordEncoder` bean. For example, if you are using Java Configuration, you can create a configuration that looks like:
>
> Reverting to `NoOpPasswordEncoder` is not considered to be secure. You should instead migrate to using `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` to support secure password encoding.
>
> ```java
> @Bean
> public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
>     return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
> }
> ```
>
> if you are using XML configuration, you can expose a `PasswordEncoder` with the id `passwordEncoder`:
>
> ```xml
> <b:bean id="passwordEncoder"
>    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.NoOpPasswordEncoder" factory-method="getInstance"/>
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can prefix all of your passwords with the correct id and continue to use `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`. For example, if you are using BCrypt, you would migrate your password from something like:
>
> ```
> $2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> {bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
> ```

Comment: To elaborate the smoking gun here is when you attempt to get a token at /oauth/token using a plaintext client-id and plaintext password in the Basic Authorization. The fix was to Bcrypt the existing client secrets in the backing SQL database. The error in the logs is `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt` because the password wasn't encoded as anything in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

OAuth2 AuthorizationServer uses basic authentication.

So, you also need to encode your client secret with delegatedPasswordEncoder in AuthorizationServerConfig to completely solve "There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" " exception.

Yao Liu's answer solved my problem.

1) created a bean to auto wire PasswordEncoder;

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoderMap = new HashMap<>();
    encoderMap.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoderMap);
}
```

2) Auto wired passwordEncoder in AuthorizationServerConfig class;

```java
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

3) encoded CLIENT_SECRET with passwordEncoder.

```java
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer
         .inMemory()
         .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
         .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(CLIENT_SECRET))
         .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_FOR_LOGIN, GRANT_TYPE_FOR_REFRESH)
         .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE)
         .accessTokenValiditySeconds(TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
         .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
         .resourceIds(RESOURCES_IDS);
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

As @false_memories stated above, with Spring Boot 2 you need to encode your secret. In my project, it looks like:

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    String secretEncoded = passwordEncoder().encode("secret");
    clients.inMemory().withClient("some-web-app").secret(secretEncoded).accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
            .scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").resourceIds("resource");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to close the loop on this question. In addition to encrypting the client-secrets. The `RedisTokenStore` issue has also been resolved as of Spring OAuth 2.3.2: [Spring OAuth 2.3.2](https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/12/spring-security-oauth-2-3-2-released)