# Spring 5 Security: 'There is no passwordencoder mapped for the id null'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to run a basic security application and when I enter the credentials in Postman, I do not receive a token like expected. I am following a basic tutorial and have followed all the steps correctly, yet I get 401 'unauthorized' status. I have tried with Bcrypt password Encoder and I get the same result

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;


    @Configuration
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authManager;


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception{
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager);
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("webapp").secret("websecret").authorizedGrantTypes("password").scopes("read,write,trust");
        }

    }
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()  throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER");
    }









}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SpringMicroserviceOathApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMicroserviceOathApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
pom.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-microservice-oath</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-microservice-oath</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 2.0.0 + OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122867/spring-boot-2-0-0-oauth2)

Comment: I had the same experience. It's like they didn't even test their own demo

Answer (score 2):

Register a bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and use the encoder in your `password("password1")` and in your `secret("websecret")`.

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1")
            .password(this.passwordEncoder().encode("password1")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    // ...

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("webapp").secret(passwordEncoder.encode("websecret")).authorizedGrantTypes("password").scopes("read,write,trust");
    }

}
```