# Spring Security XML based configuration : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

trying to test simple authentiction using spring security 5 based xml configurations.
i am having this error here are my XML configurations files

spring-security.xml

```
 <beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="1234"
                    authorities="hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    </beans:beans>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.demo.controller">
    </context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

is there any configuration that i should add to support passwordEncoding?
here is my controller

```
package com.demo.controller;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

     @Controller
     public class HomeController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String home() {
        return "home";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String privateHome() {
        return "privatePage";
     }
    }
```

for my web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <!DOCTYPE xml>
     <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <!-- Spring Configuration -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
     </context-param>
    </web-app>
```

i am using spring mvc 5.0.2.RELEASE
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.0.0 + OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122867/spring-boot-2-0-0-oauth2)

Answer (score 0):

for those who are facing the same issue, the solution is to add this config to spring-securit. xml

```
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
</authentication-provider>
```

After that authentication should work correctly.